ext4 boot partition setup for a raspberrypi with u-boot
I'm trying to make a raspberry-pi CM4 work with u-boot and an ext4 boot partition instead of the regular vfat. This is necessary for an OTA update to happen also for the boot partition with a tool called RAUC.
QUESTION: What is the advised u-boot script to handle the ext4 boot partition?
The minimal viable example of boot.scr for a running vfat partition is as below:
fdt addr ${fdt_addr} && fdt get value bootargs /chosen bootargs

fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} @@KERNEL_IMAGETYPE@@
if test ! -e mmc 0:1 uboot.env; then saveenv; fi;
@@KERNEL_BOOTCMD@@ ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}

The boot partition is the first one on the image, created with wic tool. I've found out that ext4load command should make it possible to load things from the ext4 /boot, however swapping fatload to ext4load does not work. The board does not boot.
The other thing enabled are kernel config options CONFIG_CMD_EXT4 and CONFIG_CMD_EXT4_WRITE.

If you have access to your u-boot prompt, you should be able to test these command manually and check if it works properly. Then modify your script.
You can also use "load" command instead of fatload. Make sure CONFIG_CMD_FS_GENERIC=y.
Also what framework are you using for OTA ? Mender ? software update ?
I think this script should be okay .. Just test it manually. tell me if you need help

"however swapping fatload to ext4load does not work. The board does not boot." - Negative summations are incomplete and not helpful. How far does the boot progress? FWIW I don't use RPi, but other SBCs that utilize a VFAT boot partition (on SD card) absolutely require it. This requirement is built into the first-stage boot program, i.e. the ROM boot program. IOW on those systems you can add an ext4 filesystem for U-Boot to use, but the VFAT filesystem is still needed to store the second-stage bootloader image.

@void_brain, I've decided on RAUC and read about this approach being successful, but with an NXP or ST board, not a raspberrypi. I'm having problems with getting to u-boot via UART - the serial output read by another RPI is very messy, the carriege return sign seems to be going crazy at times. I did get to the u-boot prompt on the rpi with a vfat setup, but not on the ext4.

@sawdust perhaps my approach is not the right one. What I'm really trying to achieve is to update the whole system (except for the bootloader), including the device trees, the overlays, the kernel image and the rootfs. As of now, the only things that is getting updated is the rootfs - that's the default for RAUC. I could try something called a standard boot, where the kernel and dt files are kept on rootfs, however the instructions are not exactly clear to me, nor are there any tutorials available for RPI.

"I did get to the u-boot prompt on the rpi with a vfat setup, but not on the ext4." - Still a negative summation, but a sliver of detail. That probably implies that there's a prior boot program that expects to find the u-boot.bin image in a VFAT filesystem. You probably cannot remove the VFAT filesystem from the SD card; it looks to be a requirement of the boot procedure.

Does eMMC change things compared to the SD card?
It does seem that raspberrypi requires at least one VFAT partition. Now I'm thinking about a solution similar to u-boot's standard boot, where everything except for the u-boot related scripts would be stored in the rootfs partition /boot directory.
The other way around would be to copy new boot related files from the rootfs partition to the boot partition during the update (copy only the files, not overwrite the whole partition), however I do not know yet if that is something RAUC and supports.
